# How to implement form_tag helpers without actionview?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, block, erb, view-helpers

I'm working on a Sinatra app and want to write my own form helpers.  In my erb file I want to use the rails 2.3 style syntax and pass a block to a form_helper method:

```
<% form_helper 'action' do |f| %>  
  <%= f.label 'name' %>  
  <%= f.field 'name' %>  
  <%= f.button 'name' %>  
<% end %>
```

Then in my simplified form helper I can create a FormBuilder class and yield the methods to the erb block like so:

```
module ViewHelpers  
  class FormBuilder  
    def label(name)
      name  
    end  
    def field(name)
      name  
    end  
    def button(name)
      name  
    end  
  end  
  def form_helper(action) 
    form = FormBuilder.new 
    yield(form)  
  end  
end
```

What I don't understand is how to output the surrounding `<form></form>` tags.  Is there a way to append text on only the first and last `<%= f.___ %>` tags?

Comment: I would suggest using [**Padrino's form helpers and/or builders**](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/application-helpers#form-helpers) instead of rolling your own. The gem is available as a standalone plug-in and can be used with any Ruby framework.

Comment: Padrino, or using portions of it is a really good suggestion and I may yet go that route.  I mostly wanted to make sure I understand how things go together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails has had to use some tricks in order to get block helpers to work as wanted, and they changed moving from Rails 2 to Rails 3 (see the blogposts [Simplifying Rails Block Helpers](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/08/31/simplifying-rails-block-helpers-with-a-side-of-rubinius/) and [Block Helpers in Rails 3](http://timelessrepo.com/block-helpers-in-rails3) for more info).

The `form_for` helper in Rails 2.3 works by [directly writing to the output buffer from the method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.18/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L281-283), using the Rails `concat` method. In order to do something similar in Sinatra, you’ll need to find a way of writing to the output from your helper in the same way.

Erb works by creating Ruby code that builds up the output in a variable. It also allows you to set the name of this variable, by default it is `_erbout` (or `_buf` in Erubis). If you change this to be an instance variable rather than a local variable (i.e. provide a variable name that starts with `@`) you can access it from helpers. (Rails uses the name [`@output_buffer`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.18/actionpack/lib/action_view/template_handlers/erb.rb#L21)).

Sinatra uses [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) for rendering templates, and Tilt provides an `:outvar` option for setting the variable name in Erb or Erubis templates.

Here’s an example of how this would work:

```ruby
# set the name of the output variable
set :erb, :outvar => '@output_buffer'

helpers do
  def form_helper
    # use the new name to write directly to the output buffer
    @output_buffer << "<form>\n"

    # yield to the block (this is a simplified example, you'll want
    # to yield your FormBuilder object here)
    yield

    # after the block has returned, write any closing text
    @output_buffer << "</form>\n"
  end
end
```

With this (fairly simple) example, an Erb template like this:

```erb
<% form_helper do %>
  ... call other methods here
<% end %>
```

results in the generated HTML:

```html
<form>
  ... call other methods here
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - setting the `:outvar` to an instance variable and writing to it was the missing puzzle piece.  I'll have to spend some time digging into Tilt and Erb, but this has me up and running.