# Using Blocks in erb's (Sinatra, not Rails)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I would like to use the ruby block/yield concept in an erb (to be specific, so that I can use form_helpers). When I do so I get syntax errors, but not in my erb code; in the outputted code once erb's have been processed.

For example, let's say I have the following helper:

```
def test_method   # assume this returns some string
    yield if block_given?
end
```

and I have this erb code:

```
<%= test_method do %>
    <h1>asdf</h1>
<% end %>
```

the result is:

`syntax error, unexpected ')' ; @_out_buf.concat(( test_method do ).to_s)`

I understand that the first line is converted to code independently of the other lines.  What I don't understand is why or how to fix it.  thanks!

---

ruby: 1.9.3-p392

sinatra: 1.42

anything else I can provide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement form\_tag helpers without actionview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581256/how-to-implement-form-tag-helpers-without-actionview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove output helper before test_method call in erb so it looks like:

`<% test_method do %>`

= helper expects a singleline expression to be given, not multiline.

More detailed info could be found [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/127114), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737252/print-in-erb-without) and [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).

Comment: does that mean that you can't use padrino's form_for in an erb (a helper method which returns a string)?  http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/application-helpers#formbuilders

Comment: Sure you can. Note a dash before form_for helper call in examples. You could use it the same way in your code: ```<%- test_method do %>```

Comment: thanks for the help @4pcbr. I must have some non-standard erb rendering engine, because I get the following with the `<%- %>` syntax: `undefined method '-@' for #<String:0x007fd18d989930>` -- an error message for which it is quite difficult to search.

Comment: Does it work if you remove ```<%-``` and use it just as ```<% ... %>```?